Buzzing/humming noise water pipes
When I run water or flush toilet, a buzzing/humming noise can be heard loudly in the house even out to the meter. It can be heard at the neighbors house just to illustrate how loud it is. Someone please tell me what this is before it drives us crazy.

measure the pressure, and fix the pressure regulator, set to 60 psi
